# org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.FeatureNotFoundException in Eclipse Juno on Ubuntu while loading descriptor

Tags: eclipse, maven-plugin, ubuntu-12.04, eclipse-juno

I have a GWT+GAE project which is using spring security as well. The project was running fine before I migrate it to Maven. Now after its been converted to maven project eclipse is giving following error every time I try to build the proj.

> An internal error occurred during: "Loading descriptor for MyProj.".
>   org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.FeatureNotFoundException: Feature
>   'system-properties' not found.
>   (platform:/resource/MyProj/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml, 65, 22)

Eclipse version : Juno Service Release 1
OS : Ubuntu 12.04
Plugin : m2e maven plugin.

I tried disabling validations but still error is persisting. I also tried adding the system-properties tag in web.xml as suggested in error, but that too didn't help.

Interesting thing is that, I am able to run the project but this error on every build is very annoying.

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: FeatureNotFoundException in Juno]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the error. It its because  was defined for the log property in web.xml which should ideally be in appengine-web.xml. After removing that property  tag error has gone.